# How do I get a file system path from an OPEN_DOCUMENT intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, filechooser

I'm building an android app in which I have to read a file from the `Downloads` folder of my Motorola G 2015 phone running Android Marshmallow (API v23).

To achieve this I'd like to choose the file via an `OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `GET_CONTENT` intent to leverage existing file-browsers on the user's phone, rather than implementing my own.

My manifest declares :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have tried to receive the result from the intent like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case action_choose_file:
            Intent chooseFile;
            Intent intent;
            chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            chooseFile.setType("application/epub+zip");
            intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
            return true;
        .....
    }
}
```

To process the result I do this:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String filePath = uri.getPath();
                final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            }
            break;
    ....
    }
}
```

However `new FileInputStream` fails with a `ENOENT`- file does not exist exception, and logging `filePath` reveals that it's value is something like `/documents/2055` rather than the real filepath.

I suspect that I need something like querying `DocumentProvider`, but I could not find a case similar to mine.
It's worth mentioning that a couple of years ago my code used to work pretty much like this so I suspect something changed about the way android handles file access.

How do I access a file from the `Downloads` location of my android phone?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I get a file system path from an OPEN_DOCUMENT intent?

You don't. There is no requirement that there be a file for that `Uri`, let alone one that you can access.

> However new FileInputStream fails with a ENOENT- file does not exist exception, and logging filePath reveals that it's value is something like /documents/2055 rather than the real filepath.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` and/or `openOutputStream()` to get a stream on the data represented by that `Uri`.

> How do I access a file from the Downloads location of my android phone?

Either use [an existing file-browsing library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35), or write your own file-browsing UI. The Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and kin) is for allowing the *user* to choose the content from where the *user* has chosen to store it, whether that be in a `Downloads/` directory, or Google Drive, or Dropbox, or anywhere else.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you gave some examples.

Comment: @SebastianWozny: Gave some examples of what?

Comment: e.g.: How do I use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream` to get a stream? Why can't I use `FileInputStream`? I can't make sense of the last paragraph either. Why do I need android-arsenal when my phone has a filebrowser  built in? What do I do with the result of this intent and how do Ispecifically implement this in code?

Comment: @SebastianWozny: "How do I use a ContentResolver and openInputStream to get a stream?" -- `final InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#open-client). "Why can't I use FileInputStream?" -- because a `Uri` is not a file. "when my phone has a filebrowser built in?" -- that's not a file browser.

Comment: Upvoted because an answer does not need to do your job, just lead you in the right direction!